# jQuery - button disabled but can't be enabled again

Tags: jquery, html

This is my HTML Form and jQuery code, if password and confirm password do not match then a message is shown and along with that the submit button is getting disabled. But when the password matches, the error message disappears but button is not getting enabled. Kindly help.

```js
$('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
    $('#regbtn').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#message').html('');
  } else
    $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
  $('#regbtn').prop('disabled', true);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="emailus" class="" method="post" action="session.php">
  <div class="signupform">
    <div>
      <input class="inputbox" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="inputbox" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="inputbox" type="Number" name="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="inputbox" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="inputbox" type="password" id="confirm_password" name="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm password" required><span id='message'></span>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea class="inputbox" name="Company" placeholder="Company" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <textarea class="inputbox" name="Designation" placeholder="Designation" required></textarea>
    </div>
    <div>
      <input class="inputbox submiit" type="submit" id="regbtn" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="modal fade">
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing brackets `{}` in your else statement if you add these it works.

```
$('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
    $('#regbtn').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#message').html('');
  } else {
    $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
    $('#regbtn').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

**demo**

```js
$('#password, #confirm_password').on('keyup', function() {
  if ($('#password').val() == $('#confirm_password').val()) {
    $('#regbtn').prop('disabled', false);
    $('#message').html('');
  } else {
    $('#message').html('Not Matching').css('color', 'red');
    $('#regbtn').prop('disabled', true);
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form name="emailus" class="" method="post" action="session.php">
  <div class="signupform">

    <div><input class="inputbox" type="text" name="Name" placeholder="Name" required></div>
    <div><input class="inputbox" type="email" name="Email" placeholder="Email" required></div>
    <div><input class="inputbox" type="Number" name="Mobile" placeholder="Mobile" required></div>
    <div><input class="inputbox" type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password" required></div>
    <div><input class="inputbox" type="password" id="confirm_password" name="txtConfirmPassword" placeholder="Confirm password" required><span id='message'></span></div>
    <div><textarea class="inputbox" name="Company" placeholder="Company" required></textarea></div>
    <div><textarea class="inputbox" name="Designation" placeholder="Designation" required></textarea></div>
    <div>
      <input class="inputbox submiit" type="submit" id="regbtn" name="Submit" value="Submit" class="modal fade">
    </div>

  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: @JahangirAlam Could be time to start using a decent IDE that will reformat your code for you?  Even the SO snippet editor would have highlighted this for you if you'd added it as a snippet and clicked 'tidy'.